# Drag a marker breaks on google maps when fast mouse move

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drag-and-drop, google-maps-markers

**I have a marker in a google maps**. I use this marker to retrieve the coordinate and update the lat and long in a form. When **the user drops the marker** I read the coordinates. My code is as follows:

```
    $wnd.marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                map : $wnd.map,
                draggable : true,
                icon : "/gmapsMarker.png",
                iconShadow : "/gmapsMarkerShadow.png",
                position : defaultPosition,
                clickable : true
            });

    var toggleBounce = function(e) {
        var lat = $wnd.marker.position.lat();
        var lng = $wnd.marker.position.lng();
        update(lat,lng,false);
    }.bind(this);

    google.maps.event.addListener($wnd.marker, 'dragend', toggleBounce);
```

What is the problem?

Weirdly there is no problem in *Internet Explorer 7,8 and 9*.

In *chrome* and *firefox* I get some problems while I have the marker dragged. If I **move the mouse too fast** that the pointer gets outsie of the marker's bounding box, **the marker stucks**. I need to release the mouse click, drag again de marker and drop it in my favourite position slowly.

Any recommendation?

I tried with the event "mouseup" with similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you

```
google.maps.event.addListener($wnd.marker, 'dragend', function() {
    // Get the Current position, where the pointer was dropped
    var point = $wnd.marker.getPosition();
    // Center the map at given point
    $wnd.map.panTo(point);
    // Update
    update(point.lat(), point.lng(),false);
});
```

[**You may like this**](http://heera.it/dynamic-google-map) (You can download the demo, only 8kb, [direct download link](http://heera.it/downloads/google_dynamic_map.zip)).